# Netscaler Load Balancing Persistance to specific member?

Tags: load-balancing, netscaler

In the Netscaler load balancing persistence rules it is straightforward to sticky a client IP to the same member each time.

What I would like to do is sticky a client IP to a *specific* member server, rather than the one it happened to get first time.

This is for testing purposes, so we can push a client toward each of the specific members in the service group.

This is on 10.5.

Answer (score 0):

Is you question still relevant?

Could you elaborate on the type of traffic you want to load-balance?
For HTTP/SSL traffic, there is a fairly easy solution by assigning a Server ID to a member server while adding it to a service group.

By setting persistence to a rule, you can use the server id (string value) to direct traffic to a specific member server.

You can get the server id from anywhere in the L7 data.